# R: What does the frequency argument to xts do?

Tags: r, xts, zoo

There is a formal argument `frequency` in the constructor for `xts` objects, `xts`. The help manual says:

> **frequency**  numeric indicating frequency of order.by. See details.

However, `frequency` is then not mentioned again in the manual entry. Here is an example to show that it does not do much.

```
library(xts)
xts_x = xts(x <- rnorm(120), 
    order.by = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2015-01-01"), length.out = 120, by = "day"),
    frequency = 30)
frequency(xts_x)
```

Which returns frequency of 1. My broader objective is to set `frequency` while constructing the `xts` object.

Comment: See my comment and the accepted answer to the question this duplicates.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Haha, that is a duplicate if there ever was one. But why is the `frequency` argument there? Can you give an example of where it is useful?

Comment: The `zoo` constructor has it, and xts extends zoo, so that's why the `xts` constructor has it. I would like it to be supported, and it's on my to-do list, but it's not a high priority.